# How to use opencv::highgui::get_trackbar_position

Tags: opencv, rust, highgui

I just posted so recently but I'm new to rust and keep hitting walls with what I imagine is elementary for someone more documentation-literate than I am.

I have been recreating my python code listed here

```py
while True:

    cv2.namedWindow("HSV")
    cv2.resizeWindow("HSV",640,480)
    cv2.createTrackbar("HUE MIN","HSV",0,179,empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("HUE MAX","HSV",0,179,empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("SAT MIN","HSV",0,255,empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("SAT MAX","HSV",0,255,empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("VAL MIN","HSV",0,255,empty)
    cv2.createTrackbar("VAL MAX","HSV",0,255,empty)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
            
            hsvframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

            h_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("HUE MIN","HSV")
            h_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("HUE MAX","HSV")
            s_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("SAT MIN","HSV")
            s_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("SAT MAX","HSV")
            v_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("VAL MIN","HSV")
            v_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("VAL MAX","HSV")
        

            lower = np.array([h_min,s_min,v_min])
            upper = np.array([h_max,s_max,v_max])
            mask = cv2.inRange(hsvframe,lower,upper)
            result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)

            print(lower,upper)

            out.write(mask)
            cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
            pass
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
```

---

I have been trying to recreate this while loop in rust and cant seem to understand how to call the position with opencv::highgui::get_trackbar_pos like cv2.getTrackbarPos

I also dont necessarily understand `loop {}` and its nuances so im not sure what the equivalent `ret, frame = cap.read, if ret==True:` would be because it seems like rust's `cvt_color` handles that so I dont know if it affects where my `get_trackbar_pos` should be

---

Lastly I'm really not sure how I should be writing to a lower and upper set of arrays so any advice there would be helpful.

```rust
use std::f32::MAX;

use opencv::{ highgui::{self, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE}, imgproc, prelude::*, videoio, Result};

fn run() -> Result<()> {

    let window = "video capture";
    let hsv = "HSV";
   
    
    highgui::named_window(window, 1)?;
    highgui::named_window(hsv, 1)?;
    
    highgui::named_window(hsv, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)?;
    highgui::create_trackbar("HUE MAX", hsv, None, 179, None)?;
    highgui::create_trackbar("HUE MIN", hsv, None, 179, None)?;
    highgui::create_trackbar("SAT MAX", hsv, None, 179, None)?;
    highgui::create_trackbar("SAT MIN", hsv, None, 179, None)?;
    highgui::create_trackbar("VAL MAX", hsv, None, 179, None)?;
    highgui::create_trackbar("VAL MIN", hsv, None, 179, None)?;

    opencv::opencv_branch_32! {
        let mut cam = videoio::VideoCapture::new_default(0)?; // 0 is the default camera
    }
    opencv::not_opencv_branch_32! {
        let mut cam = videoio::VideoCapture::new(0, videoio::CAP_ANY)?; // 0 is the default camera
    }
    let opened = videoio::VideoCapture::is_opened(&cam)?;
    if !opened {
        panic!("Unable to open default camera!");
    }

    loop {
        let mut frame = Mat::default();
        cam.read(&mut frame)?;
        if frame.size()?.width > 0 {
            let mut gray = Mat::default();
            
            let h_max = opencv::highgui::get_trackbar_pos("HUE MAX", hsv)?;
            let h_min = opencv::highgui::get_trackbar_pos("HUE MIN", hsv)?;
            let s_max = opencv::highgui::get_trackbar_pos("SAT MAX", hsv)?;
            let s_min = opencv::highgui::get_trackbar_pos("SAT MIN", hsv)?;
            let v_max = opencv::highgui::get_trackbar_pos("VAL MAX", hsv)?;
            let v_min = opencv::highgui::get_trackbar_pos("VAL MIN", hsv)?;

            let _lower = [h_min, s_min, v_min];
            let _upper = [h_max, s_max, v_max];

            imgproc::cvt_color(&frame, &mut gray, imgproc::COLOR_BGR2HSV, 0)?;
            highgui::imshow(window, &gray)?;
        }
        if highgui::wait_key(10)? > 0 {
            break;
        }
    }
    Ok(())

}

fn main() {

    run().unwrap()

}
```

Here is my `main.rs`

You can see at the bottom my loop and arrays.

The [Rust OpenCV Documentation](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.26.6/opencv/highgui/fn.get_trackbar_pos.html) seems really simple and clear, I'm just fairly rust illiterate and even reading the rust book I'm having trouble.

Comment: Looks like you have two loops in the python code but only one in the Rust code. Why is that?

Comment: `cam.read(&mut frame)?` should return a `bool` that you can check, similar to python.

Comment: @PitaJ Two loops in python is just how the original tutorial I used setup their trackbars in python. As for rust, I'm not sure why I am able to successfully get an HSV stream with that code (just no trackbar control)

also is the cam.read handling what the `ret, cap.read` handles?

Comment: In the python wrapper, `VideoCapture::read` returns a tuple of `(success, image)` where `success` is a boolean and `image` is the captured frame (may be empty when it didn't succeed). Since rust can use reference parameters, you only get a boolean signifying whether the read succeeded or not. When the read fails, you want to exit to loop. | https://docs.rs/opencv/0.26.6/opencv/videoio/struct.VideoCapture.html#method.read

Comment: @PitaJ I wouldn't worry about the two loops in Python code. That outer loop appears pointless as is, and the inner one might as well be `while(True)`, since once `cap.isOpened()` returns `True` it will always do so, even after a read fails. | The check of the result of `cam.read` should definitely be done, in order to break out when end-of-file is reached or camera read fails.

Comment: Your usage of `get_trackbar_pos` seems OK. Is the problem in how to call [`in_range`](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.26.6/opencv/core/fn.in_range.html)? If so, [edit] your question (including the title) to reflect that. If you have multiple questions, then it might be a good idea to split this up, so you only ask a single question per question.